# How to properly clean a iris into an list with array and integer

Tags: python, string

How would one best transform a iris

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.2,5.0,1.5,Iris-virginica
```

into this [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2], 0] and so on. Iris-versicolor would get the 1 and Iris-virginica would get the 2

I am currently learning about multiclass perceptron but it seems that my class fails to do any operation on my iris since im transforming it incorectly.

With my code I get a list cointaining strings.

```
import numpy as np
def read_iris(filename):


with open (filename) as f:
    linelist=list()
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("Iris-setosa", "0").replace("Iris-versicolor", "1").replace("Iris-virginica", "2")
        if "\n" in line:
            line = line.replace("\n", " ") 
            for element in line.split(','):
                linelist.append(element)
            data = [ linelist [i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(linelist), 5) ]
    return data

 ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', '0 ']
```

That's what I would get from this code

Comment: If I understand you correctly, do you want to parse the text file and create lists `[[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2],0]` etc... ?

Comment: Correct that's is my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, here is one example how you can parse the file (the file is named `sample.txt` and contains the data as stated in the question. Feel free to rename it as you want):

```
transform = {
    'Iris-setosa': 0,
    'Iris-versicolor': 1,
    'Iris-virginica': 2
}

data = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        row = line.strip().split(',')
        data.append( [[*map(float, row[:-1])], transform[row[-1]]] )

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
[[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2], 0],
 [[4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2], 0],
 [[4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2], 0],
 [[7.0, 3.2, 4.7, 1.4], 1],
 [[6.0, 2.2, 5.0, 1.5], 2]]
```

Comment: Im getting a keyerror when I run it myself: <ipython-input-32-ed1f09cc4740> in read_iris(filename)
     11         for line in f_in:
     12             row = line.strip().split(',')
---> 13             data.append( [[*map(float, row[:-1])], transform[row[-1]]] )
     14 
     15     """Reads the iris file into memory.

KeyError: ''

Comment: @RandomDog In the last column, you have probably something different than `'Iris-setosa'`, `'Iris-versicolor'` or `'Iris-virginica'`. You can change `transform[row[-1]]]` to `transform.get(row[-1], -1)`, where `-1` is the default value if none of the three values are found

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have one last question. For some reason the end of my print is showing me a , [ [ ], -1]) which looks odd to me.

Comment: @RandomDog Thats probably because you have empty line (only `\n`) in your output file. You can filter the empty line out, e.g. to `if not line.strip(): continue` inside the loop.